# Firebase cloud function - Pupeteer do not find element in cloud but works in emulator

Tags: firebase, web-scraping, google-cloud-functions, web-crawler, puppeteer

I'm trying to crawl some data from a webpage with a puppeteer. I created the whole script and ran it in the emulator, locally in the emulator everything works fine. When I deploy the same thing to the cloud and run it the puppeteer cannot find an element and ends execution.

My code:

```
console.log('Scraping LINKS');
const browser = await getBrowser();
const page = await preparePage(browser, `URL`);
console.log('Page opened');
const handle = await page.$('.sloupec_s_inzeratama');
console.log('Finding handle');
if (!handle) {
    console.log('Can not find "sloupec_s_inzeratama"');
}
if (handle) { 
    // Do something else
}
```

Log as a screenshot from console:

[image]

What I tried and didn't help:

- commented out all puppeteers start args
- change loading strategy from: "domcontentloaded" to things like "load" or "networkidle2"

  await page.goto(url, {
  waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded',
  });
- Used [waitForSelector](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitforselector) before I tried to find a selector. (It just timed out)

Obviously, there is some difference between what happens in the emulator and what happens in cloud functions. But I'm not able to tell what is a difference and how should I debug that. So any advice is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

After some time of debugging, I added `page.content()` to a console log to verify data was the same as on my localhost. I found out that Recaptcha V3 detected my server as a BOT and disabled it to continue. However, my emulator still works fine.

I always tried to scrape slowly without hurting someone's server but it still means your puppeteer can be detected in case someone gets to the same issue verify your bot just didn't get detected :)